# Macro Creation in MS Word .docm not allowed

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a VB macro in MS Word in order to automatically format the background colour of content control dropdowns.

I am using a .docm document and setting my content controls like so:

[image]

[image]

I then selected the 'Macros' button in the developer tab but for some reason I was not able to create a macro via the pop-up as the buttons are greyed out.

[image]

I created a new macro via the 'Visual Basic' button the developer tab but it doesn't seem to run.

I think this is due to where the code is being saved, under the 'Normal' header  in the editor sidebar, but when I try to select the actual document project I get a pop up error.

[image]

[image]

My Code

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
With ContentControl.Range
    If ContentControl.Title = "IssueSeverity" Then
        Select Case .Text
            Case "CRITICAL"
                .Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorDarkRed
            Case "HIGH"
                .Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            Case "MEDIUM"
                .Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorOrange
            Case "LOW"
                .Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGreen
            Case "INFO"
                .Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBlue
            Case Else
                .Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        End Select
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

What do I need to do within Word (latest version) in order to get macros working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may have the same issue solved by [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24357424/6193229).

It basically talks about write access to the startup folder where the template is located.

> **Option #1**
>
> Copy template OUT of Start Up Folder, right click file and select
> "Open" You can [run/]debug it.
>
> **Option #2**
>
> Ensure you have write permission to file in startup folder. Even if
> you are Admin, if UAC is ON you won't have access - grant your user
> "full control" or "write access to file" to DOTM file in startup
> folder.